# Google Nearby blocks Android application accessing to Internet - it switches to Wifi Direct automatically

Tags: android, wifi-direct, google-nearby

I am having a problem with Google Nearby and WiFi Direct.I am developing an Android application which will run on two Android devices simultaneously.

These devices are connected via Google Nearby and in the same time both Android devices need to be connected to Internet for some API calls.

But sometimes,Google Nearby enables Wifi Direct automatically and in that case the devices are unable to access the Internet for API calls,hence the requests are failing.

I am unable find a way to prevent Nearby API from using WiFi Direct as connection medium in Lenovo Tab 7 Essentials devices.

How to programmatically control Nearby connection like "not to use" WiFi Direct?

Kind regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use P2P_CLUSTER; P2P_STAR is inherently disruptive.

P2P_CLUSTER will use Bluetooth and LAN to connect your devices, so expect slower speeds if you're not both connected to the same router.

P2P_STAR will use Bluetooth, LAN, and Hotspots to connect your devices, so it gets higher bandwidth but it can cause devices to disconnect from their Wifi network.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I converted it to P2P_CLUSTER mode. Now it does not connect to WiFi direct; but Nearby continuously disconnects in five minutes interval. When I check the internet connection, it shows as connected; but I cannot browse.. WhenI turn airplane-mode on and then off, it comes back to normal, I can browse internet and I can connect devices with Nearby. I could not understand why this problem is occurring.

Comment: Which version of NearBy dependency you are using? Is it 12.0.1?@develotr